# how to allign a div in center in responsive website

Tags: css

I have a problem in my website that one div of my website is alligned Left but i had to make it appear in middle of the webpage whatever be the screen size is.
Here's the live link:

```
 http://m.greatofficiants.com
```

I need to allign the header content in the middle of the page.

Comment: do you mean the whole header or the just the content to be center?

Comment: just Image and the two text lines present

Comment: .outer .header{background:url(images/header.png) 0 0 repeat-x; min-height:90px; padding:10px 10px; position:relative;}

Comment: @Vinay what about just inspecting he's site?

Comment: @SimonPertersen Already you gave the correct explanation to him. I am the one Upvoted you. :)

Comment: @Simonpertersen I guess you don't like my upvote aren't you?

Comment: @Vinay ofc i like it - but it was just a heads up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take down your `float:left` for .social and put a `margin:0 auto;` and a width:x% and `text-align:center` would give a plus to this that class. I think you may also have to reajust some child elements of .social.

Comment: Thanks it worked man.. i'll be uploading this change on live after some hours.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it with

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

This [link](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) will explain you in depth how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of your basics of a responsive website is totally wrong...

You need to build all in 100% not px

So if you have a padding and a width

it would be like

```
padding:2%;
width:96%;
```

the hole site should be build in this manor before your site is good enough - then you start centering items

**Edit** *

note you can have objects inside your site which have width...
But the **main frame** of your website should strictly be build of **percentages**...

If you wanna center a div with width of 320px fx.
which is the lowest width of a phone
So state the width of the object and then add a margin: 0 auto;

**Edit** **

So in your case you wanna add

```
width:100%;
```

to both body and wrapper
then all your text wraps should be in the same manor that explain before(the padding can vary) depending on your website but i find 2% as a good margin

```
padding:2%;
width:96%;
```

**Edit** ***

And last i just spotted that you have IE stylesheets you dont need that when developing for making mobile websites its just 3 extra calls which in the long run makes your website slower

Follow this [link](http://html5boilerplate.com/) to have a good plate to work out from.. Its a boilerplate which makes yoru site faster and have all the right scripts and css files to go out from

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.header {
  width:1000px; /* what ever size you want*/
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: This code centers the div, not the content of the div. I'm not sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="social">
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://m.greatofficiants.com"><img src="http://m.greatofficiants.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/logo3.png"/></a>
    <div class="im2"><p style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">Toll Free (855) Wed-Vows</p></div><br />
    <div class="im1"><p style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"> Local (562) 435-4000</p></div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried but it didnot worked.